# Is the time complexity of this loop O(n*log(n))?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'd be very grateful if someone explained to me how to analyse the time complexity of this loop:

```
int t;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
t = i;
    while(t > 0){
        t = t/2 
   }
}
```

I'm inclined to think that is O(n*log(n)) since it's very similar to:

```
int t;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    t = n;
    while(t > 0){
        t = t/2 
   }
}
```

but it does less assignments to the variable t. Is this the case?
If it's the case, How could  I arrive to this conclusion more rigorously?

Comment: The while loop never ends since `i` is never assigned again?

Comment: Why do you expect your `while` loop to end?

Comment: Sorry, I had written i instead of t inside the while's guard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first snippet, the inner loop runs `log(1) + log(2) + ... + log(n)` times, which is the same as `log(1 * 2 * ... * n) = log(n!)` which through Sterling's Approximation is `n log(n)`. Your second snippet has the same complexity. Even if it happens to do less assignments we only care about the overall behavior. In this case both are linearithmic.